# Overload ambiguity in direct initialization with conversion functions

Tags: c++, overloading, implicit-conversion

The following code is used as an example to help me understand the implicit conversion sequence and function overload in the process of direct initialisation. The example is rather simple.

Class `B` doesn't have any constructor that accepts object of type `C`. Class `C`, on the other hand, implements two user-define conversion operators, see line [5] and [6]. (Qualifier `const` on line [3] is to help me understand the impact of qualifier on function overloading, in case you question the intent of that line.)

```
class B;

class A {
public:
    A() {}
    operator B();
};

class B {
public:
    B() {std::cout << "default constructor B::B() \n";}                            // [1]
    explicit B(A&) { std::cout << "B::B(A&) \n"; }             // [2]
    explicit B(const A&) { std::cout << "B::B(const A&) \n"; } // [3]
};

A::operator B() { std::cout << "conversion A::B() \n"; return B(); } // [4]

// Ambiguity issue
class C {
public:
    C() {}
    explicit operator A() { std::cout << "conversion C::A() \n"; return A(); } // [5]
    explicit operator B() { std::cout << "conversion C::B() \n"; return B(); } // [6]

//  explicit operator A() { std::cout << "conversion C::A() \n"; return A(); } // [7]
//  operator B() { std::cout << "conversion C::B() \n"; return B(); }          // [8]

// Combinations that trigger ambiguous overload.    
//  operator A() { std::cout << "conversion C::A() \n"; return A(); }          // [9]
//  explicit operator B() { std::cout << "conversion C::B() \n"; return B(); } // [10]

//  operator A() { std::cout << "conversion C::A() \n"; return A(); }          // [11]
//  operator B() { std::cout << "conversion C::B() \n"; return B(); }          // [12]
};

int main() {
    C c;     // [21]
    B b (c); // [22]
}
```

At [22], when both conversion operators of `C` are labelled `explicit` ([5] and [6]), or only `C::A()` is `explicit` ([7] and [8]), compiler is silent and printing

```
conversion operator C::B() 
default constructor B::B()
```

which suggests that (correct me if I am wrong), per direct initialisation, object `c` is converted into a temporary object of type `B` via its conversion function. This can be understood, since conversion into type `B` appears to be more straightforward (than first into `A` and to `B`) as the target type is exactly `B`.

Combinations [9,10] and [11,12], i.e. making conversion to type `C::A()` implicit, trigger the following error on ambiguous overload:

```
test.cpp:189:12: error: call of overloaded ‘B(C&)’ is ambiguous
  189 |     B b (c);
      |            ^
test.cpp:94:14: note: candidate: ‘B::B(const A&)’
   94 |     explicit B(const A&) {              
      |              ^
test.cpp:85:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr B::B(const B&)’
   85 | class B {
      |       ^
test.cpp:85:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr B::B(B&&)’
```

I don't understand this ambiguity in overload. Indeed, converting `c` to type `A` and then invoking a constructor of `B` is one option. But, direct conversion into `B` is available and that conversion sequence appears to be "shorter" and is thus "better".

I am sure that I missed some implicit conversion or overload resolution rules from the C++ reference website. Can anyone point out to me the relevant "rules"? Compiler version is `g++ 9.3.0`.

Comment: [overload_resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) might interest you.

Comment: Both `B(const A&)` and `B(B&&)` are viables, and none is better than the other (both need a conversion from `C`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Actually I was reading the resolution and I must admit without concrete example, most rules are not really straightforward. Could you please point out to me the part of the resolution that explains, in the current situation, "none is better than the other". Would be very helpful.

Comment: Not simple indeed, in particular, as it is not just a single rule to see, but all *"tie-breaker"* which are not applicable.
From *"Ranking of implicit conversion sequences"*, they both need an user-defined conversion. and from "Best viable function", No point make one function better than the other one.